# Can "I dare say (so)" mean "Of course" in a certain context?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, idioms-in-context

Can the expression "I dare say (so)" mean "Of course" in a certain context?

I know the general meaning and usage of this expression.

From Collins dictionary:

> You can use 'I dare say' or 'I daresay' before or after a
> statement to indicate that you believe it is probably true. "I dare say
> that the computer would provide a clear answer to that."  "People always
> think I'm a fool, and I dare say they're right."  "Luke badly wanted a
> pass mark. Still does, I daresay."

But I was wondering if, when the context makes it clear, this expression can be used in an ironic way to mean "of course".

For example, suppose someone has done many bad things to you, and a friend asks you, "Are you angry with him?" and you reply, "I dare say (so)", when it is clear you actually mean "To say the least", or, "I certainly am".

I think I heard this usage in a movie, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it can; but I don't think people would use it when it is about their _own_ actions or feelings. So it might be a reply to _Is he angry with you?_, but  it's odd in the case you give. I think this is a consequence of the fact that its normal (non-sarcastic) meaning is generally about things that the speaker doesn't know directly.

Comment: It's become a set phrase / cliche, but ***I dare say*** hasn't really drifted that far from it's original *literal* meaning *(I will venture to say something that may elicit a hostile reaction, **because others may not accept it**)*. But mostly today it just means ***perhaps*** - so instead of being essentially ***I think this, but you might disagree***, it's now come to have more the flavour of ***someone might think this** [but **someone else** might disagree]*.